# How to restart guest OS without starting from the beginning?

Tags: virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox again and I want to restart the Guest OS Windows 10. But as I recall, when I reboot the Guest OS, it starts again from the beginning, like I have do do the installation again from the top.

Do I have to use `Devices` > `Optical Drives` > `Remove Disk From Virtual Drive` before rebooting the Guest OS? I am using the latest version of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 12):

This will only happen if you have the option enabled to discard changes. When you make a snapshot, you can then set the Virtual Machine to always discard changes made after the snapshot when the VM is shutdown.

Simply disable that option, and you can reboot/power off normally and keep all changes.

Also, make sure there isn't an ISO or CD mounted that does an OS installation. Normally this should be bypassed, but it could happen if you changed the boot order.

Answer (score 0):

Change your boot devices/order to remove the CD/DVD drive from the list of devices it'll boot from. Then it doesn't matter whether there's a bootable CD/DVD/ISO attached.  Your current VisualBox settings will look something like this:-

[image: VirtualBox VM settings]

Deselect "Optical" from the "Boot order" list, and you're sorted.